# Fancy URL structure, conditional content, and search - using CPT, custom fields and taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

We're building a directory of automotive-related businesses in 3 countries - USA, Canada and Mexico.

I created a custom post type 'Listings' and tried to move on with the following.

For various SEO purposes we need specific URL structures as follows:

**1) Individual listing page**

Nothing too fancy - ***domain.com/usa/listing-slug***

**2) Per-state archives**

Nothing too fancy as well - ***domain.com/usa/texas***

**3) Per-city archives**

This one is more interesting, we need the following structure:

- ***domain.com/usa/cleveland/oh***
- ***domain.com/usa/cleveland/nd***

Where the 1st one is archive for Cleveland, Ohio and the other one for Cleveland, Nevada.

**4) Per-ZIP archives**

Pretty usual - ***domain.com/usa/05657***

**5) Mixed location-category archives**

- ***domain.com/usa/cleveland/oh/car-parts***
- ***domain.com/usa/ohio/car-parts***
- ***domain.com/usa/05657/car-parts***

**6) Custom content (templates) for all above archive pages, except maybe ZIP**

We're trying to somewhat mimic [this website](http://www.familydaysout.com/).

If you check, let's say, the same examples for Cleveland, Ohio and Cleveland, Nevada: http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/cleveland/oh and http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/cleveland/nd you'll see what I mean - these pages have custom content (descriptions) in the beginning.

Above are per-city custom content examples. The same exists for per-state http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/ohio and mixed:
http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/ohio/major-theme-parks
http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/cleveland/oh/major-theme-parks
http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/5601/major-theme-parks

I got to the point where I can auto-populate location data when adding a new listing, so when I paste a full address, e.g. "21200 Saint Clair Avenue Euclid, Ohio 44117" and save I get this:

[image: automatically populated custom fields]

As you can see, country, state, city and ZIP are all there. Category (Car Parts) is also there as a listing category.

Now how can I use these values to construct URLs and pages/templates for archives? Should I automatically convert custom field values to custom taxonomies and go from there? I know I can do this with https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post and https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

I know custom taxonomies can have descriptions and I know how to output these descriptions. Besides that, taxonomies can be hierarchical, so I can add Ohio and Nevada as parents and each Cleveland as a child for them.

So I'm at the point where I managed to collect and store all the info bits, but not sure how to start manipulating them to achieve the above model.

**Q1**: Where should I store location data (country, state, city, zip) to be able to use it in URLs as described above? Custom fields or taxonomy terms?

**Q2**: How do I build archive pages/templates as described above in a way that I can customize templates for them?

Any other helpful tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you don't to explore other options, but with a complex URL structure that will only get more complicated and harder to mange, you might want to look at a php routing framework like http://www.slimframework.com/.  I would also recommend writing the front end as an API, e.g. use a templating system in php (twig) or javascript (knockout, angular etc). You can still easily get access to the WordPress database via $wpdb(). Alternatively, have a look at the WordPress rewrite API https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the rewrite API. Alternative frontend isn't an option, at least not right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching around, I think I can help you now.

#### 1. Register `location` taxonomy to create base archive slug:

```
function wpso36667674_register_location_taxonomy() {
    $labels = [
        'name'          => _x('Locations', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'wpso'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Location', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'wpso'),
        'all_items'     => __('All Locations', 'wpso'),
    ];
    $args = [
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'rewrite'       => ['hierarchical' => true],
    ];
    register_taxonomy('location', 'listing', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wpso36667674_register_location_taxonomy', 0);
```

We have to change the terms' slugs which are automatically generated by WordPress to sanitized terms' names so that the URLs' structure look as you wished for:

```
function wpso36667674_filter_term_link($term_link, $term, $taxonomy) {
    $term_link = rtrim($term_link, '/');
    $pos = strrpos($term_link, '/');
    $term_link = substr($term_link, 0, $pos + 1) . sanitize_title($term->name);
    return $term_link;
}
add_filter('term_link', 'wpso36667674_filter_term_link', 0, 3);
```

**Caution**: Do not enter terms' slugs manually when adding new terms, let WordPress generate it for us or we will not be able to query terms' posts contents correctly. The reason is the two URLs: `location/usa/ohio/cleveland` and `location/usa/idaho/cleveland` give us the same posts because WordPress only uses `cleveland` as term for querying posts' contents without caring about the parent term.

#### 2. Register `listing` post type like this:

```
function wpso36667674_register_listing_post_type() {
    $labels = [
        'name'          => _x('Listings', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'wpso'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Listing', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'wpso'),
        'all_items'     => __('All Listings', 'wpse'),
    ];
    $args = [
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-location-alt',
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'supports'      => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'],
        'taxonomies'    => ['location'],
        'rewrite'       => ['slug' => '%country%/%state%/%city%/%zip%'],
    ];
    register_post_type('listing', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'wpso36667674_register_listing_post_type', 0);
```

We're not sure whether the listing has state|city|zip or not, so we have to use substitutes (`%country%/%state%/%city%/%zip%`). Then replace it with each listing meta data (From my experience with WordPress, you should store location data in each listing):

```
function wpso36667674_filter_post_link($post_link, $post, $leave_name = false, $sample = false) {
    $zip = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'geolocation_postcode', true);
    $city = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'geolocation_city_short', true);
    $state = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'geolocation_state_short', true);
    $country = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'geolocation_country_short', true);
    $post_link = str_replace('%zip%', $zip, $post_link);
    $post_link = str_replace('%city%', $city, $post_link);
    $post_link = str_replace('%state%', $state, $post_link);
    $post_link = str_replace('%country%', $country, $post_link);
    $post_link = preg_replace('/[^:](\/{2,})/', '/', $post_link);  // Remove multiple forward slashes except http://.
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'wpso36667674_filter_post_link', 0, 4);
```

**Note**: If your use uppercase short names, you must convert it to lowercase when modifying URLs' structure.

#### 3. Add rewrite rules to make our custom URLs work correctly.

```
// Add rewrite rules for location taxonomy.
function wpso36667674_add_location_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^location/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxonomy=location&term=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxonomy=location&term=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^location/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?taxonomy=location&term=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'wpso36667674_add_location_rewrite_rules', 0);

// Add rewrite rules for listings.
function wpso36667674_add_listing_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^usa/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^usa/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^usa/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^usa/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[4]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^mexico/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^mexico/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^mexico/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^mexico/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[4]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^canada/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^canada/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^canada/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^canada/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=listing&name=$matches[4]', 'top');    
}
add_action('init', 'wpso36667674_add_listing_rewrite_rules', 0);
```

#### 4. Return back the correct terms' slugs:

As I said, by changing `usa/idaho/cleveland-idaho` to `usa/idaho/cleveland` in permalinks, queried posts for `usa/idaho/cleveland` are same as `usa/ohio/cleveland`. So we must help WordPress know what is the correct term slug to use for querying posts' contents:

```
function wpso36667674_modify_requested_url($query) {
    if ( $query->query_vars['taxonomy'] === 'location' ) {
        $slugs = array_filter( explode('/', $query->request) );
        $term = array_pop($slugs) . '-' . array_pop($slugs);
        if ( get_term_by('slug', $term, 'location') ) {
            $query->query_vars['term'] = $term;
        }
    }
}
add_action('parse_request', 'wpso36667674_modify_requested_url');
```

Thanks to [@Jevuska](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/18731/jevuska) for suggesting to use `parse_request`.

#### 5. Create a custom template for each archive location:

Thanks to [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com), we can do it easily.

Example:

For `location/usa/ohio`, the template will be `taxonomy-location-ohio.php`.

But remember that we must use the actual terms' slugs which generated by WordPress, not what we modified in URLs.

Example:

If Cleveland in Ohio was added before Cleveland in Idaho, the term slug of the first is `cleveland` and the second will be `cleveland-idaho`.

Then, template for the first is `taxonomy-location-cleveland.php` and the second is `taxonomy-location-cleveland-idaho.php`.

That's all! All code you can put directly inside `functions.php` file. Remember to flush the permalink settings too.

Comment: Thanks Den, that rocks! One last question: where do I approach listing categories from? I mean, like "Theme Parks": http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/ohio/major-theme-parks and http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/cleveland/oh/major-theme-parks. These categories must exist for states and cities and I should be able to have templates for them as well. I mean, I can add "Theme Parks" as a category for CPT "Listings" and most likely I'll do it that way. But how do I get separate templates for them? I'm very close, but still missing this bit.

Comment: @bugnumber9 Hmm! If you don't enter slugs manually and Major Theme Parks in Ohio was added before Major Theme Parks in Cleveland. Then, for `domain.com/location/usa/ohio/major-theme-parks`, the template should be `taxonomy-location-major-theme-parks.php` and for `domain.com/location/usa/ohio/cleveland/major-theme-parks`, the template is `taxonomy-location-major-theme-parks-cleveland.php`

Comment: Hey @Dan, I've got a small problem here. I'm using your code and everything seems smooth, except one thing. It strips the last letter of a domain name for a location. E.g. what should be domain.com/five-star-autos/ becomes domain.co/five-star-autos/
I was able to troubleshoot this down to this line: `$post_link = preg_replace('/[^:](\/{2,})/', '/', $post_link);` but can't understand where exactly it strips the 'm' from .com

Comment: @bugnumber9 That sounds weird. I will test the regex again ;-)

Comment: I know it's been a while, I was busy with the design part all this time :) But I guess I've got more issues here. Fancy getting a paid gig? ;)

Comment: @bugnumber9 I'm sure that it isn't caused by the regex. You should check for typing errors, plugins' filters... Btw, WordPress has its own limitation :)

Answer (score 0):

As per you requirements , you can achieve this by creation of categories as described below :

> `domain.com/usa/cleveland/oh` and  `domain.com/usa/cleveland/nd`

1. Cleveland, Ohio (/usa/cleveland/oh)
2. Cleveland, Nevada (/usa/cleveland/nd)

So create a parent category as "USA" and then child category as "Cleveland" and under that one more child category as "Ohio" and its slug as "oh".

So hierarchy should be `USA->Cleveland->Ohio` and in slugs it should be `usa->cleveland->oh`

Similarly, `USA->Cleveland->Nevada` and slugs as `usa->cleveland->nd`

Now , For the posts to be displayed at URL :

1. domain.com/category/usa = provide them "USA" category
2. domain.com/category/usa/cleveland/ = provide them "Cleveland"
   category
3. domain.com/category/usa/cleveland/oh = Provide them "Ohio"
       category

Now you only need to remove the `category` from URL . So for that write the below code in the `.htaccess` file located in the root folder.

```
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

Comment: The parent category USA will work, everything else won't. Once I create the 1st Cleveland - it's slug will be /cleveland/, all other ones will become like /cleveland-1/ or like that. And that's the problem - WP requires slugs to be unique.

Comment: @bugnumber9 That sounds weird! I don't think WordPress creates categories' slugs like that.

Comment: Dan, it does. Another problem is that I'll have to create 'state' child categories for each 'city' category. I mean, if we imagine we have Cleveland and Lone Pines in 50 states - I'll end up creating Cleveland and Lone Pines under USA, and 50 identical sub-categories for each.
Now even if I go this route - Idaho and Ohio for Cleveland will have /ohio/ and /idaho/ slugs, the same for Lone Pines will be /idaho-lone-pines/ and /ohio-lone-pines/

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do when all states are unique sub-categories of a unique country. The same rules apply for cities, towns and so on.
Why do you have to create `Cleveland` category for all 50 states?

Comment: Dan, even if I do "country -> state -> city" hierarchy - yes, all state slugs will be unique because all states are unique. But city names aren't unique, e.g. Cleveland in Ohio and Cleveland in Idaho. So the 1st Cleveland will have slug /usa/ohio/cleveland/, but the other one will be /usa/idaho/cleveland-idaho/ or /usa/idaho/cleveland-1/. Try that yourself on any WP install, you can't have categories (regardless of their 'level', meaning parent-child) with the same slug.

Comment: Dan, here's another part that probably describes the problem better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679146/non-unique-term-slugs-or-anything-else-i-can-use-to-build-specific-pages-and-pe

Comment: you can achieve this by using ACF.. use same city name for all the same name categories and in the ACF dropdown select the state name to which it belongs to .. and in the archive page (listing page).. write condition to check for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 ways to solve your problem
First one is to use mod_rewrite to transfer you suggested formatted URLs to associate template php file and handle your request there the way you want.
For this following link might help. Google for more https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

The 2nd approach would be follow the wordpress page template hierarchy and create template pages accordingly and handle similar requests in template php. For details explanation refer to https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/

and a quick page template hierarchy to understand which page template will execute for particular url refer to https://media-mediatemple.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/01-wp-template-hierarchy-opt.jpg