# Non-unique term slugs, or anything else I can use to build specific pages and permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, custom-fields, slug

My project is a directory of business listings.

Individual listing URL looks as simple as *domain.com/five-star-cars* - something that WordPress handles out of the box.

But I have a problem drilling into region-based archives. We need a specific URL structure for those. For example, if we want to show all listings in Ohio, we need *domain.com/ohio* - also simple.

However, if we want to show all listings in Cleveland, Ohio and Cleveland, Nevada - we want to do this:

- *domain.com/cleveland/oh*
- *domain.com/cleveland/nd*

So I created a CPT "Listings" and a custom taxonomy "Location". I added Ohio and Nevada as parent terms and Cleveland as children to both.

Here's the issue: the slug of the 1st Cleveland is *domain.com/location/ohio/cleveland/* but the 2nd one became *domain.com/location/nevada/cleveland-nevada/*

I found out that term slugs must be unique, so that's a problem - I can't use term slugs to build URLs.

What I did next is saving state and city as custom field values in each listing. Now I can use these values (which, unlike term slugs, don't have to be unique) as global variables via something like this:

```
function loc_global_vars() {
 global $wp_query;
 $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
 global $loc_vars;
 $loc_vars = array(
    'state'     => get_post_meta($postid, 'state', true),
    'city'      => get_post_meta($postid, 'city', true),
);
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'loc_global_vars' );
```

But now I'm stuck: what are my next steps?

**Q1**: How do I build archive pages and permalinks using these variables?

**Q2**: How do I build templates so that I'm able to customize them for every archive type?

Or is there anything obvious that I've missed and I'm simply looking into a wrong direction?
So, generally:

**Q3**: Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), you can use your post meta to build URLs.

1) Add your post meta terms via `add_rewrite_tag()`

2) Set a `add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/?','index.php?state=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]','top');`

3) Flush the rewrite rules after you set your hooks, for example by saving a permalinks setting @ `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`.

There's a write up [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Addressing Q3, you could use [Cortex](https://github.com/Brain-WP/Cortex), a WP routing system.

Or, less inelegant solution, why not create two custom post types, one for cities and one for regions, and a custom tax to put the cities on the region pages?

Comment: Not going to have cities on state pages, just listings from the whole state and state-specific description at the top, like http://www.familydaysout.com/kids-things-to-do-usa/ohio

Comment: @spnzr You should clarify your answer with examples. Because references are often hard to follow for other people who haven't figured out how it work.